# Why did Niobe mention "luckily" in this line?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Niobe successfully lands Hammer ship at Zion:

> Morpheus: You're a hell of a pilot.
>
> Niobe: Some things in this world never change.
>
> Morpheus: But some things do?
>
> Niobe: **Luckily**......some things do.

Why did Niobe mention "luckily" in this line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a callback to the Matrix Reloaded:

> Niobe: I remember. I remember you used to dance. I remember you were
> pretty good.
>
> Morpheus: There are some things in this world, captain Niobe, that
> will never change.
>
> [they get interrupted]
>
> Morpheus: Some things do change.

Basically they’re talking about their romantic history. Naomi saying ”luckily” things do change indicates she’s open to her relationship status changing, i.e. getting back with Morpheus.